# Find common rows of 2 dataframe for 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 Python pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
DF1=
    A    B   C    D
0   AA   BA  KK   0
1   AD   BD  LL   0
2   AF   BF  MM   0

DF2=
    K    L
0   AA   BA
1   AD   BF
```

At the end what I want to get is:

```
DF1=
    A    B   C    D
0   AA   BA  KK   1
1   AD   BD  LL   0
2   AF   BF  MM   0
```

So, I want to compare two dataframe, I want to see which rows of first data frame (for column A and B) are in common of of second dataframe(Column K and L) and assign 1 on the coulmn D of first dataframe.

I have been using the following code:

```
print (df1['A'].isin(df2['A']) & df1['B'].isin(df2['B'])).astype(int)
```

But this is not exactly what I am expecting

How it can be achieved?

Comment: I think that this question belongs to StackOverflow and, hopefully, moderators will migrate it there for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is simply by using `merge` function to choose which keys you want to join on.

So firstly, if we create some kind of indicator in `DF2`, and joining, we have:

```
DF2['inDF2'] = 1
DF3 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how='left', left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['K', 'L'])
```

You can then simply add the columns `D` and `inDF2` to get the required result.

```
DF3['D'] = DF3['D'] + DF3['inDF2'].fillna(0)
```

Dropping the relevant columns will get the data set that you're after:

```
DF3.drop(['K', 'L', 'inDF2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

With the output:

```
>>> DF3
    A   B   C  D
0  AA  BA  KK  1
1  AD  BD  LL  0
2  AF  BF  MM  0
```

---

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {
'A' : ['AA', 'AD', 'AF'],
'B' : ['BA', 'BD', 'BF'],
'C' : ['KK', 'LL', 'MM'],
'D' : [0, 0, 0]
}

d2 = {
'K' : ['AA', 'AD'],
'L' : ['BA', 'BF']
}

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
DF2['inDF2'] = 1

DF3 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how='left', left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['K', 'L'])
DF3['D'] = DF3['D'] + DF3['inDF2'].fillna(0)
DF3.drop(['K', 'L', 'inDF2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```